# How do i protect my game assets as an individual?

Tags: copyright

For my first games, they will be well made, complete, but extremely simple, while i father enough funds to actually fund a game company.

But because I plan on releasing quality content under {insert my name here} Studio (trademark)(c)

and of course all of my games will be superseded by a (c), despite the fact I haven't even registered anything.

*But the real question is, what steps do I need to take to make sure my content does not get stolen while im financially stable enough to file all the paperwork needed to maintain proper copyrights?*

I'd also like to release a major title, but I'm scared to, because I know someone is going to try and steal it.

Comment: If you do not have a trademark, do not pretend you have a trademark. However, you do have copyright, at least in most jurisdictions you do... yes, without any paperwork, in most jurisdictions. In a legal case you would have to provide evidence of your original work. Doing the paperwork to register your work with the goverment beforehand is not a bad idea, what paperwork and how expensive depends on where you are (edit: where I am it is free and done online)... That question is off-topic here. Perhaps ask a notary?

Comment: You can also take a look at [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5691/40264).

Comment: @Theraot federal and state registration: A trademark does not need to be registered for the owner to prevent others from using a trademark or from using a confusingly similar mark

Comment: @anon0 state? federal? We are clearly not in the same part of the world.

Comment: and that's why i love living in the USA lol